# The letter "i" appears capitalised even when I don't mean to capitalise them

Tags: posts, headers

For some reason, the letter "i" always appears as a capital (I) even when I don't want them to. Does anyone know of a possible fix?

See below for an example. The word here is "Shopping".

[image]

The theme I'm using is "twentyseventeen".

**EDIT:** Seems like it's just a browser/PC issue with font rendering; works fine on other PCs I've tested. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: We would have to see the code or have a link... probably is an L, like Shopplng, xD

Comment: @Castiblanco it isn't an "L". You can see it at batamsg.com/do. If you copy the header and paste it else where, you'll see it's an "i".

Comment: It's just a rendering issue with the font. It appears fine to me in Chrome on Windows 10. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: @JacobPeattie Chrome on Windows 10. I'll try on another computer/browser. Thanks.

Comment: Looking good for me as well: https://screenshots.firefox.com/Tpi33d9MpJbVlukR/batamsg.com

Comment: @Castiblanco that's odd - must just be my browser/computer then, thanks!

Comment: @paoye If you have solved your own problem, please write about it as an answer. That will help others as they wander around this place.

Comment: Seems like it's just a browser/PC issue with font rendering; works fine on other PCs I've tested. Thanks for all your help!